# keyUp event not working [WinForm]

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got some controls on the Panel and I am trying to delete them using "Delete" button. I handled KeyPress Event as mentioned in How to get Keypress event in Windows Panel control

Comment: Well..! can you please share the code

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           
        } on main form i have panel thats why i am not able to fire keyup event

Comment: Please avoid sharing your code in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question.

Comment: thank you @ZoharPeled.. will try to avoid this from next time

Comment: You cannot get the form's KeyUp event to fire when a control on the panel has the focus.  Use KeyDown instead with KeyPreview=true or favor overriding ProcessCmdKey()

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the event `MainForm_KeyUp` does not even get fired on your key up, because you have focues another control. But you can fix that with `KeyPreview`.

A `Form` object has the property `KeyPreview`. According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

So when you set:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

You enable that your `MainForm` gets notified about those key events always. Even when any other `Control` is focused. So you enable that those key events will invoke `MainForm_KeyUp()`.

Now set a breakpoint:

```
private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //set a breakpoint here, so you get confirmation, that the event will get fired 
    //on key up of the *delete* button

    //...now do what you desire
}
```